# Changing file name while writing back file in output folder in Data Lake Storage account in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-data-lake

It would be so much helpful if you would help me in my problem.

In my project requirement, I have to store the file with some specific name in Data Lake Store in Microsoft Azure (cloud based platform). After performing any transformation or action on the data frame created by the loaded file in HDInsight cluster, when I am writing the data frame to any specific folder, it gets stored with name "part-00000-xxxx" i.e in hadoop format.

But, as I am having large number of files so I can't go inside the created folder for each file and rename the same specific to my requirement every time.

So, can you please help me out in this?

NOTE: After storing the file we can copy the file to another folder and while copying we can give name whatever we want.But I don't want this solution. I want to provide a specific name to the file once I am writing it back to my storage(Data Lake Store) after processing.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a subclass of the MultipleOutputFormat class to control the pattern of the filenames, but that will need to be in Java, since you can't write OutputFormats with the streaming API.

Another option might be to use the Azure Storage client to merge, and rename the output files once the job is over.